# place one raphael js element inside another

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I've got a Raphael.js image that I've done, which consists of a set of circles, like so

```
var paper = Raphael(0,0,100,100);
var circle1 = paper.circ(20,20,10);
var circle2 = paper.circ(40,40,10);
```

I also have an svg icon in Raphael format (thanks to the lovely site http://readysetraphael.com/) that I'd like to place inside of each circle. Problem is... all the paths in the converted svg icon are now relative to the point (0,0) ! By this is mean all the strings are written like this

```
paper.path('M 1 1 L 2 0 L 0,2 z')
```

So my question ... is there some clever way to 'relativise' this path to make it sit inside each circle, without just going in and changing every single element of the path string by hand to make it draw the same path twice inside the two circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. Replace the contents of shp with any other valid path.

```
    var shape,
        circleHalfWidth,
        circleHalfHeight,
        shpHalfHeight,
        shpHalfWidth,
        targetLeft,
        targetTop,
        paper,
        circle1,
        circBBox,
        shpBBox,
        shp,
        radius = 20,
        b2,
        c2,
        b,
        s;

shape = "M25.979,12.896,5.979,12.896,5.979,19.562,25.979,19.562z";
paper = new Raphael(0,0,500,500);
circle1 = paper.circle(100,100,radius);
shp = paper.path( shape );

// get objects that contain dimensions of circle and shape

circBBox = circle1.getBBox( );
shpBBox = shp.getBBox( );

// get dimensions that will help us calculate coordinates to centre of circle

circleHalfWidth = circBBox.width / 2;
circleHalfHeight = circBBox.height / 2;
shpHalfWidth = shpBBox.width / 2;
shpHalfHeight = shpBBox.height / 2;

// calculate coordinates to position shape on top left corner of circle

targetLeft = circle1.getBBox( ).x - shp.getBBox( ).x;
targetTop = circle1.getBBox( ).y - shp.getBBox( ).y;

//Calculate how wide is shape allowed to be in circle using pythagoras

c2 = Math.pow( radius, 2 );
b2 = c2 / 2;
b = Math.sqrt( b2 );

// Calculate ratio so that both height and width fit in circle

s = shpBBox.width > shpBBox.height ? ( shpBBox.width / b ) : ( shpBBox.height / b );

// change coordinates so shape will be moved to centre of circle

targetLeft += circleHalfWidth - shpHalfWidth;
targetTop += circleHalfHeight - shpHalfHeight;

// Remember uppercase T so that scaling is ignored when moving shape 

shp.transform( "s" + s  + "T" + targetLeft + "," + targetTop );
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4dpew/2/)